# Javascript to validate element values and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I want to use js to check a form in the case that none of my checkboxes are checked and the input field hasn't been filled. When this is the case, the user should get a message that tells them to make at least one choice or formulate their own.

The form elements...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxA" id="checkboxA" value="X" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxB" id="checkboxB" value="Y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxC" id="checkboxC" value="Z" />

<input type="text" id="Text" class="textfield" value="please enter text." maxlength="100" size="40" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'please enter text';}"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'please enter text') {this.value = '';}" />
```

...are checked by this js function when the POST method is performed:

```
function checkFormElement() {
if ((document.getElementById("text").value == "please enter text.")
    && (document.getElementById("checkboxA").checked == false)
    && (document.getElementById("checkboxB").checked == false)
    && (document.getElementById("checkboxC").checked == false)){
        alert("Please choose out of X Y Z or formulate your own choice .");
        document.getElementById("checkboxA").focus();
    return false;
    }
return true;
```

}

I guess using jQuery should be much easier but I still love to know how to solve this in pure js.

Comment: So, what is your question?  What are you having problems with in your code?  What doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case matters with ID values so change this:

```
document.getElementById("text").value
```

to this to match what you have in your HTML:

```
document.getElementById("Text").value
```

Once I fix the case issue and put in code to actually call `checkFormElement()`, it seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9DHxF/

Comment: or change the html to "text" :)

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't give me the alert message. Checked for typos (such as the given uppercase lowercase) but still no succes..

Comment: @Kiwi1 - Are you calling `checkFormElement()` somewhere?  It isn't called in the code you have in your question.  When I call it and fix the case error, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9DHxF/.

Comment: @jfriend00: looked again at my code and found out I still had some typos here and there. should be looking out for these before hitting the forums :). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `submit` or similar type of button\option that will run `checkFormElement()`.
Once you include something that calls this function, you shouldn't experience any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code.  Mostly mismatched IDs and such.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/E8SBq/

This should work for you:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxA" id="checkboxA" value="X" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxB" id="checkboxB" value="Y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxC" id="checkboxC" value="Z" />

<input type="text" id="Text" class="textfield" value="please enter text" maxlength="100" size="40" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'please enter text';}"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'please enter text') {this.value = '';}" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="checkFormElement()" />
```

And the JS function:

```
function checkFormElement() {
if (document.getElementById("Text").value != null  
    && document.getElementById("checkboxA").checked == false
    && document.getElementById("checkboxB").checked == false
    && document.getElementById("checkboxC").checked == false) {
        alert("Please choose out of X Y Z or formulate your own choice .");
        document.getElementById("checkboxA").focus();
    return false;
    }
return true;

}
```

Comment: Please note, the `onblur` event of the text field prevents a `null` value. So you should keep Kiwi1's original code.
Also in my experience, the `submit` button works better in a `<form>`. You should be able to get the same functionality with a regular button and not trigger any possible form actions.